# How to convert numpy array to image dataset?

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

Here I used **PIL Library** to load image and it's a single data not for **image dataset** and convert numpy array using **numpy Library**. It's perfectly working for single image data.

**Now,** I want to convert into numpy array from image dataset. where will be presented **training**, **testing** and **validation** data.

*below I share the code for converting single image data to numpy array.*

> Imported needed library

```
from PIL import Image
from numpy import asarray
```

> load the image

```
image = Image.open('flower/1.jpg')
```

> convert image to numpy array

```
data = asarray(image)
#data is array format of image
```

Comment: How would you import your image dataset?

Comment: @amzon-ex I code on "google colab". So upload image dataset and then unzip the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to convert the numpy array back to image then following code snipped should work. If you want replicate the process for entire dataset then you need to call it on every single image. How you do it would depend on the model you're trying to build(image classification, object detection etc) and what you're using to build it(tensorflow, theano, etc)

**Solution 1**

```
from PIL import Image 
from numpy import asarray
image = Image.open('flower/1.jpg')
data = asarray(image)

img_w, img_h = 200, 200
img = Image.fromarray(data, 'RGB')
img.save('test.png')
img.show()
```

Since you're working on an image classification problem. The following code could serve you well. Customize it as per your problem. I've commented in the code where you need to make the changes.

**Solution 2**

```
from PIL import ImageFile
ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True

import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import cv2
from glob import glob

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.applications import MobileNetV2 #Change Here: Select the classification architecture you need
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, ReduceLROnPlateau
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

def build_model(size, num_classes):
    inputs = Input((size, size, 3))
    backbone = MobileNetV2(input_tensor=inputs, include_top=False, weights="imagenet") #Change Here: Select the classification architecture you need
    backbone.trainable = True
    x = backbone.output
    x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
    x = Dropout(0.2)(x) #Chage Here: Try different droput values b/w .2 to .8
    x = Dense(1024, activation="relu")(x)
    x = Dense(num_classes, activation="softmax")(x)

    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, x)
    return model

def read_image(path, size):
    image = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, 
                                   rotation_range=30, #Change Here: Select any rotation range b/w 10 to 90
                                   zoom_range = 0.3, 
                                   width_shift_range=0.2, #Change Here: Select width shift as per your images. My advice- try b/w .2 to .5
                                   height_shift_range=0.2, #Change Here: Select height shift as per your images., My advice try b/w .2 to .5
                                   horizontal_flip = 'true') 
    
    image = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(path, shuffle=False, batch_size=10, seed=10) #Change Here: Select batch_size as per your need
    image = cv2.resize(image, (size, size))
    image = image / 255.0
    image = image.astype(np.float32)
    return image

def parse_data(x, y):
    x = x.decode()

    num_class = 120 #Change Here: num_class should be equal to types of blood cells you have in your dataset i.e. number of labels
    size = 224 #Change Here: Select size as per your chosen model architecture 

    image = read_image(x, size)
    label = [0] * num_class
    label[y] = 1
    label = np.array(label)
    label = label.astype(np.int32)

    return image, label

def tf_parse(x, y):
    x, y = tf.numpy_function(parse_data, [x, y], [tf.float32, tf.int32])
    x.set_shape((224, 224, 3))
    y.set_shape((120))
    return x, y

def tf_dataset(x, y, batch=8): #Change Here: Choose default batch size as per your needs
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x, y))
    dataset = dataset.map(tf_parse)
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch)
    dataset = dataset.repeat()
    return dataset

if __name__ == "__main__":
    path = "/content/gdrive/My Drive/Dog Breed Classification/" #Change Here: Give path to your parent directory
    train_path = os.path.join(path, "train/*")
    test_path = os.path.join(path, "test/*")
    labels_path = os.path.join(path, "labels.csv") #Change Here: Give name of your csv file

    labels_df = pd.read_csv(labels_path)
    breed = labels_df["breed"].unique() #Change Here: replace breed with the column name, denoting class, in your csv file
    print("Number of Breed: ", len(breed))

    breed2id = {name: i for i, name in enumerate(breed)} #Change Here: replace breed & id with the column names denoting class & image file in your csv file
                                                         #repeat the same every place where breed or id is mentioned

    ids = glob(train_path)
    labels = []

    for image_id in ids:
      # print(image_id,"\n\n\n")
      image_id = image_id.split("/")[-1]
      breed_name = list(labels_df[labels_df.id == image_id]["breed"])[0]
      breed_idx = breed2id[breed_name]
      labels.append(breed_idx)


    ## Spliting the dataset
    train_x, valid_x = train_test_split(ids, test_size=0.2, random_state=42) #Change Here: select test size as per your need. My advice go between .2 to .3
    train_y, valid_y = train_test_split(labels, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

    ## Parameters
    size = 224    #Change Here: Select size as per your chosen model architecture 
    num_classes = 120 #Change Here: num_class should be equal to types of blood cells you have in your dataset i.e. number of labels
    lr = 1e-4 #Change Here: Select as per you need. My advice chose any where b/w 1e-4 to 1e-2
    batch = 16 #Change Here: Select as per your need
    epochs = 50 #Change Here: Select as per your need

    ## Model
    model = build_model(size, num_classes)
    model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=Adam(lr), metrics=["acc"])
    # model.summary()

    ## Dataset
    train_dataset = tf_dataset(train_x, train_y, batch=batch)
    valid_dataset = tf_dataset(valid_x, valid_y, batch=batch)

    ## Training
    callbacks = [
        ModelCheckpoint("/content/gdrive/My Drive/Dog Breed Classification/Model/model-1-{epoch:02d}.h5", #Change Here :Give the path where you want to store your model
                        verbose=1, save_best_only=True),
        ReduceLROnPlateau(factor=0.1, patience=5, min_lr=1e-6)] #Change Here: Set factor, patience, min_lr as per your need. My advice leave as it is and then change to see if model performance improves.
    train_steps = (len(train_x)//batch) + 1
    valid_steps = (len(valid_x)//batch) + 1
    model.fit(train_dataset,
        steps_per_epoch=train_steps,
        validation_steps=valid_steps,
        validation_data=valid_dataset,
        epochs=epochs,
        callbacks=callbacks)
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer. Actually I am going to work  to detect various kinds of disease from a single fruits. But first of all I should make a csv file from image datasets after converting into numpy array.

Comment: If you're using keras Solution 2 should work for you